# Add select attribute to Html.DropDownList using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the the following html elements:

```
<tr>  
  <td> <label for="casenumber">Case:</label></td>
  <td>
    <%=Html.TextBox("casenumber", "", new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
      {"id", "casenumberID"}
    })%>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="fogbugzUser">Users:</label></td>
  <td>
    <%=Html.DropDownList("UserList", (SelectList)ViewData["UserList"], new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
      {"id", "userlistid"}
    })%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now, when the `casenumber` loses focus, I want to call the database to return me a selected value in the `UserList`.

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#casenumberID").blur(function() {
    //don't know how to do!!);
  });    
});
```

And here's the client side scripting:

```
public JsonResult GetOpenByUser(string casenumber)
{
  return Json(userContext.OpenBy(casenumber));
}
```

The question is how to write the function "blur" so that I can pass in the value of the textbox `casenumber` to the `GetOpenByUser`?

Also, how to complete the function `blur` so that the option that has the same value as the one that is returned by `GetOpenByUser` will be selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [this](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) for selectboxes in jquery

Answer (score 1):

The (ASP.NET MVC independent) approach you anticipated would be right:

- onblur: make Ajax request to database
- on Ajax success: read and parse response
- select appropriate value in `#fogbugzUser`

Sample code, assuming your page is returning a plain string with the ID and nothing else. Here I'm using [`get()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) to make the request, but there are more ways to do it.

```
$(function() {
  $("#casenumberID").blur(function() {
    $.get(
      "url/to/some.page/fetching.the.userid",
      // this will be turned into URL parameters, e.g.: "casenumberID=15"
      { casenumberID: this.value },
      function(result) {
        /* check if result is a string of numbers only (change for 
         * something that better suits your needs if numbers is not
         * what you expect here */
        if (/^\d+$/.test(result))
          $("#fogbugzUser").val(result);
        else
          alert("Server returned an unexpected result: " + result);
      }
    });    
  });
});
```

You could also return JSON, in your server response. In this case, [`getJSON()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback) would be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code, for those who's going to need it, tested working with ASP.NET MVC beta 1:

Server side AJAX:

```
    public JsonResult GetOpenByUser(string casenumber)
    {

        return Json(userContext.OpenBy(casenumber));
    }
```

The HTML:

```
  <form id="subForm">
    <tr>  
    <td> <label for="casenumber">Case:</label></td>
     <td><%=Html.TextBox("casenumber", "")%> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="fogbugzUser">Users:</label></td>
    <td><%=Html.DropDownList("UserList", (SelectList)ViewData["UserList"])%></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

The Script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#casenumber").blur(function() {
        $.getJSON("Home/GetOpenByUser",
    { casenumber: this.value },
    function(result) {
        if (result == "")
            return;

        $("#subForm select[@name='UserList'] option[@selected='selected']").removeAttr("selected"); //remove any selected items
        $("#subForm select[@name='UserList'] option[@value='" + result + "']").attr("selected", "selected"); //select the item that is returned from the server

    });
    });

});
```

Comment: How about $("#subForm select[@name='UserList']").val(result) ?

Comment: That would be good, but this is more succint:

$(function() {
    $("#casenumber").blur(function() {
 
  $("#UserList").val(this.value)
    });

});

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, for the JQuery script part, one can write

```
$(function() {
    $("#casenumber").blur(function() {
        $.getJSON("Home/GetOpenByUser",
    { casenumber: this.value },
    function(result) {
        if (result == "")
            return;

 $("#UserList").val(this.value)

    });
    });

});
```